# Foreach issue in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code which is supposed to print me every possible pdv which has an `id=super_selected_1`.
The issue is, if I print the `$super_selected_1` inside the while it works, it takes the value, but inside the checkbox it won't show it,
Am i doin smth wrong here?
Thanks.

```
$super=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) { 
    $super[]=$row['id_pdv'];
}

foreach($super as $super_selected_1){
    $sqlsuper_1="SELECT * FROM pdv WHERE id_pdv='$super_selected_1' AND regione_pdv='$term1'";
    $querysuper_1 = mysql_query($sqlsuper_1) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($querysuper_1,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        echo $super_selected_1;


        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  id="checkbox[]"  class="pdv_super" value="'.$row['id_pdv'].'" >' . $row['nome_pdv'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error are you getting and please dont use the query in the loop

Comment: Have you tried printing `print_r($row);`? This should show you what `$row` contains.

Comment: the checkbox is not supposed to show anything so what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't show"? It would be better if you gave an idea what the output you expect should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Your checkbox is wrong. The `value` attribute does have no effect if the type is "checkbox". You need to set `checked="checked"` in your `<input>` tag if it shold be shown as checked.